How to pull from a remote repo to a local repo, when the local repo is not empty?
I have a remote server, with a directory containing files. I have a local machine with a directory containing different files. I want to link these two directories so I can run git pull and git push in my local directory. How can I achieve this ?
I run git init on both local and remote. I run git remote add originName www.server.com:/path/to/remote/dir/ on local. I run git fetch originName. I create a new branch git branch test. I checkout this new branch git checkout test. I merge with the remote git merge remotes/originName/master.
I would expect to see the remote files in the local repo at this stage, but I only have my local files. After running git merge remotes/originName/master again git returns with a message `Already up to date.
What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding ?
In case it is relevant, my local machine is behind a firewall so I cannot run git pull or git push from my remote to my local.
Update
So far I have achieved the following:

Execute:
a) git init
b) git add *
c) git commit * -m"git commit message."
On both local and remote.
Add the remote on local:
git remote add remoteName www.url.com:/path/to/repo
Download remote:
git fetch remoteName
Create new branch locally:
git branch localBranch
Move to local branch:
git checkout localBranch
Merge the local branch with the remote:
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories remoteName/master
Address merge conflicts
I now have two branches locally - one containing local files, and one containing remote files.

Update II
I have been able to create a local and remote copy on my local machine by the following process:

Create a backup of the local directory mv dirName dirNameBackup
clone the remote repo that is also named dirName with git clone www.url.com:/path/to/dirName
Move into dirName locally and create a new local branch with git branch local
Checkout local branch git checkout local.
Remove all remote files from local with rm -r * and git add -u *

I now have the remote directory under the branch master and the local directory under the branch local.
I am able to successfully pull from remote to local by running git pull origin in my local repo. However, when I try to do the reverse, pushing from local to remote by running git push origin on local, I receive the error:
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.

I don't want to create both a bare and non-bare repo on my remote machine due to memory constraints. How can I work around this ?

Why did you run git init in both places? When in this process did you add files and commits to the remote?

I run git commit on remote after running git init. I followed the above process both with and without running git commit on local. Neither process allowed me to transfer remote files to local.
I want to transfer files from a remote git repo to a local git repo, that is why I ran git init. Is there a gap in my understanding somewhere ?

git init and commits on remote are fine, but if you do that then you don't need to replicate git init on local - git clone will initialize the local repo, associate it with the remote, and pull the latest changes. Also, git fetch updates Git's index of commits but does not update local files to reflect the latest state; git pull will fetch and then update local files.

My local directory contains files before I promote it to a git repository. Running git clone requires my local directory to be empty. I need to pull from an unrelated remote when my local contains files already.

You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be - unrelated histories are unpleasant to untangle in Git. Just move those files before cloning or clone the repo to another place (git clone URL other-path will clone the repo at URL to other-path) and copy or move the files.

I thought this would solve my issue, however I have encountered another problem - if I attempt to push into the remote origin, I get an error stating I cannot push into a non-bare repository. I do not wish to create both a bare and non-bare repo on the remote due to memory limitations. What is the alternative ?
